# Looking at allocated objects at a specific time using JProfiler

Tags: java, profiler, jprofiler

I have recently started using JProfiler to look at the performance of my application and improve it using the metrics that JProfiler provides me with.

When I monitor the GC telemetry I see that when I do a specific thing that the memory usage increases by 300MB and it's something that will happen quite often so I want to see whether I can lower that amount.

Problem is that I can't seem to figure out how I can view the allocated objects that were allocated inside the time I selected in the graph.

I use JProfiler 2017.02-b67

Answer (score 0):

The heap walker has a "Time" view where you can select objects that have been allocated in arbitrary time ranges.

[image]

You have to switch on allocation recording during the allocation spike and you have to enable allocation time recording in the profiling settings.

[image]

Comment: jProfiler 2017.02-b67 isn't the same as jProfiler 10.0.3 (in design).
https://gyazo.com/ab630d9b0c96bf35b6d8b452c154fdde

Comment: No, that's a totally different product that is not called JProfiler.

Comment: I see, my bad, my apologies. I updated the question with the correct name.

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot change the question in such a way. Please ask a new question instead.